# How can I access params in the same component where the route is

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component called `allProducts` like this

```
<div>
  <Route path='/products/:curPage' component={someComponent} />
  <Pagination />
</div>;
```

Pagination component

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router';

const Pagination = (props) => {
  const { curPage } = useParams();
  return <div></div>;
};
```

I want to access params(`curPage`) in my Pagination component. But I am getting an empty object. Is there any workaround?

Comment: The code looks good. Can you post the code where you handle the redirect to `/products/:curPage`?